# Resize tableview NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

Hi I have a tableView which I change the width programmatically by his constraint:

```
    self.widthTableLeft.constant = self.view.frame.size.width;
```

I do this in the viewDidLoad.

In the delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I need the contentview frame of each cell to calculate the hight of the cell, but when get it, this is the old size, I mean the size if I wouldn't have done the resize.

When the table is showed the size of the table is right but the hight of the cell is wrong.

I have tried to call:

```
[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

[cell.contentView setNeedsLayout];
[cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
```

The question is, before to show the view of my view controller, when is the best place to update the width constraint of a UITableView and to get the right contentView in the cells in the method heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Sorry but I'm lost, could you give me any ideas?

Thanksssss

**UPDATE**

This is the code in heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
static const NSInteger ROC_TITLE_LABEL_TAG = 2;

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

ROCAgendaItemDetailEntity *agendaItemDetail = [self.listRight objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableLeft dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellVideo"];

//I get the label which will make the cell bigger
UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:ROC_TITLE_LABEL_TAG];

//We init the height title with the min height.
float extraSpaceHeightLabel = 0;
if (agendaItemDetail.agendaItem.title.length > 0) {

    //I will use his width to get the hight that I need to write all text
    float width = titleLabel.frame.size.width;

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX);

    //we get the size
    CGSize sizeTitleLabel = [agendaItemDetail.agendaItem.title sizeWithFont:[ROCTextsInformation imagoMed:15] constrainedToSize:size lineBreakMode:titleLabel.lineBreakMode];
    //we substract the current height of the label to know the extra space to write all text
    sizeTitleLabel.height -= titleLabel.frame.size.height;
    extraSpaceHeightLabel = sizeTitleLabel.height;

}
//The final hight will be the contenViewHeight pluss the extra space needed.
return cell.contentView.frame.size.height + extraSpaceHeightLabel;
}
```

and this is the cell in the table view

[image]

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad is too early to try and access the geometries of your views. Instead, access self.view's width in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

```
@interface CustomViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isFirstTimeViewDidLayoutSubviews; // variable name could be re-factored

@end

@implementation CustomViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.isFirstTimeViewDidLayoutSubviews = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    // only after layoutSubviews executes for subviews, do constraints and frames agree (WWDC 2012 video "Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout")

    if (self.isFirstTimeViewDidLayoutSubviews) {

        // execute geometry-related code...
        self.widthTableLeft.constant = self.view.frame.size.width;
    }

    self.isFirstTimeViewDidLayoutSubviews = NO;
}
```

Comment: Hi @bilobatum thanks for your answer. I have added this in the end of the method:
`[self.view layoutSubviews];`
Because I got this error:
`Auto Layout still required after sending -viewDidLayoutSubviews to the view controller. ROCAgendaPresentationViewController's implementation needs to send -layoutSubviews to the view to invoke auto layout.'`

But unfortunately the cell contentView continues showing the old frame in: 
` - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: Post all the code inside your implementation of the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method.